# Locally constant functions and base ring extension

Tags: general-topology, modules, tensor-products

Let $X$ be any topological space, and let $R$ be any commutative ring with identity (in particular, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module). Let $C_c^{\infty}(X,R)$ be the $R$-module of locally constant functions with compact support from $X$ to $R$. I was wondering if 
$$C_c^{\infty}(X,\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}R\cong C_c^{\infty}(X,R),$$
as $R$-modules, by means of the canonical $R$-linear map $f\otimes r\mapsto rf$. The surjectivity (if I'm correct) is easy, but I could not prove the injectivity. Probably, I'm missing something elementary, sorry if that is the case.

(While trying to understand a paper by Mazur, I needed to prove this when $X$ is a profinite space and when $R$ is a field of characteristic zero, which I proved but using the fact that $X$ is profinite, by reducing to the case when $X$ is finite and discrete, which is easy. I read in another paper that the above is true so I tried to prove it, unsuccesfully.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm trying to prove that something is isomorphic to a tensor product, one thing that works a lot of the time is constructing an inverse map.  So you can define a map $\phi:C_c^{\infty}(X,R) \rightarrow C_c^{\infty}(X,\mathbb Z) \otimes_{\mathbb Z}R$ like this:

Given $f: X \rightarrow R$, taking finitely many values $c_1, ... , c_n$, let $f_i \in C_c^{\infty}(X,R)$ be the characteristic function of $f^{-1}(c_i)$.  Then $f = c_1 f_1 + \cdots + c_nf_n$, and you can define

$$\phi(f) = f_1 \otimes c_1 + \cdots + c_n \otimes f_n$$
where now you are thinking of $f_i$ as an element of $C_c^{\infty}(X,\mathbb Z)$.

You have to do a little work to show that $\phi$ is an abelian group homomorphism.  Once you do, showing that $\phi$ is inverse to the map you defined is easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That was an idea of mine, but is it always well defined? One has a "canonical" decomposition $f=c_1+\cdots+c_n$ where all the $c_i$ are different elements of $R$. If I take another decomposition of $f$, are the images under $\phi$ going to be equal?

Comment: I think I got it: $\phi$ is a function because one can define its image on the unique canonical representation of $f$ as linear combination of characteristic function. Then, one have to show that $\phi$ is additive, and this not immediately (which you said in your answer). This reduces to proving that $\phi$ is additive on linear combinations of characteristic functions, which one may write in a canonical way, apply $\phi$ and then reverse the process. Is this ok, or I'm complicating the proof?

Comment: Yes, I think that's right.  There are many ways to write $f$ as a combination of characteristic functions, but this canonical way lets you define $\phi(f)$ unambiguously.